# Redirect Vaadin App

Tags: redirect, authentication, vaadin, trial

I am currently hosting my vaadin app on openshift. My main website redirects to the vaadin app when the login button is clicked. The first thing the user sees is the login page

I have 2 buttons on my website, a free trial button and a login button, and I have 2 different classes in my vaadin app, a login class and a free trial class.

How can I make the login button redirect to the login class of my vaadin app and the free trial button redirect to the free trial class of my vaadin app?

This is what it currently looks like:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@Widgetset("com.example.myapp.MyAppWidgetset")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        login();
    }
```

Comment: I would be inclined to use a navigator here instead. You would need to refactor your code a little though.

Comment: @Chris M Thank you! Would you have any insight into how to implement this for my situation? I read through the docs but I dont really understand it. 

How can I use this to redirect www.trial.mywebsite.com to the trialUI class
And redirect www.login.mywebsite.com to the LoginUI class?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a parameter to your request and use a UI provider to serve the UI depending on this parameter.

See [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+application+with+different+features+for+different+clients).

Example:

```
public class DifferentFeaturesForDifferentClients extends UIProvider {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends UI> getUIClass(UIClassSelectionEvent event) {
        if ("trial".equalsIgnoreCase(event.getRequest().getParameter("app-type"))) {
            return TrialUI.class;
        } else {
            return LognUI.class;
        }
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>My Vaadin App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Vaadin UI</description>
        <param-name>UIProvider</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.myexampleproject.DifferentFeaturesForDifferentClients</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

And then in your main websites html code:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="app-type" value="Trial" formaction="/your/vaadin/url" formmethod="post"> 
    <input type="submit" name="app-type" value="Login" formaction="/your/vaadin/url" formmethod="post"> 

    <!-- Alternative using button tag (better for customization, but no IE < 9) -->
    <button name="app-type" value="trial" type="submit">Trial</button>
    <button name="app-type" value="login" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This seems to make sense but how will I pass in a parameter to my request?

Comment: You could use a form in your main website that passes a POST parameter when submitted using the button and target the form to the url of your vaadin application.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Alright great thank you! Will try this out. The Web.xml must be edited the way you did it correct? And I assume this will work even if my main website and vaadin app are hosted in different locations?

Comment: Yes, you will have to include the setting of the UIProvider in your web.xml, and remove the annotation. It should work if they are hosted on different locations, yes. I updated the code to correctly set & check the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Navigator as Chris M said, or you can try to implement an event driven architecture. I implemented a project like that using Vaadin too with Google Guava.

Here you can find some examples of how to use Google Guava if you are interested.
http://codingjunkie.net/guava-eventbus/

Below you can find some code fragments of my implementation:

```
// Using guava
final Button signin = new Button(
                    Lang.getMessage("login.signin"), 
                    eventClick -> {BarsEventBus.post(new UserLoginRequestedEvent(
                            username.getValue(), password.getValue()));});


//Using Navigator, I also used spring here, so the registration view is a Spring View
final Button register = new Button(
                    Lang.getMessage("login.registration"), 
                    clickEvent -> {getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(ViewToken.REGISTRO);}
                    );


@UIScope
@SpringView(name = ViewToken.REGISTRO)
public class RegistrationView extends VerticalLayout implements View {...}
```

Please verify the code for the vaadin demo application. That code is having an example on how to handle it too. Find it here:
https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo

Answer (score 0):

I now understand what you were truing to do. You can do this quite easily. You need to cast the VaadinRequest into a VaadinServletRequest. The reason it passes a VaadinRequest rather than an VaadinServletRequest is so you can deploy your application as a portlet too. In that case you would need to cast it to VaadinPortletRequest instead. Then you can use the serverName provided by the user.

```
 @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        VaadinServletRequest req = (VaadinServletRequest) vaadinRequest;
        String serverName = req.getServerName();
        if (serverName.equals("www.login.mywebsite.com"))
        {
           login();
        }
        else
        {
            trial();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This almost does what I want, but I am redirecting my app from openshift to login.mywebsite.com. The code that you provided is giving me the url for openshift, and not for login.mywebsite.com. Do you have a work around for this?